# Veeam Backup Free, Samba share and PowerShell: access denied

Tags: powershell, debian, backup, samba, veeam

I have:

- ESXi host with some virtual machines
- Veeam Backup Free Edition installed on one of the virtual machines (Windows Server 2012 R2)
- Debian host with samba on it

I succeeded with:

- Making a shared folder with samba on debian machine
- Making a manual backup using Veeam Backup GUI to the folder on debian machine

I have trouble with:

- Running backup from PowerShell script to be able to make scheduled backups.

This [topic](https://forums.veeam.com/powershell-f26/discussion-on-blog-post-update-2-featuring-powershell-t28023-300.html) on the Veeam forum suggests to

> grant Veeam account as well as Computer account read/write permissions on the given share

But I don't know how to actually grant these permissions to samba folder.

Could you please help me with granting the permissions to samba folder?

Here is the script:

```
# Author: Vladimir Eremin
# Created Date: 3/24/2015
# http://forums.veeam.com/member31097.html
# 

##################################################################
#                   User Defined Variables
##################################################################

# Names of VMs to backup separated by semicolon (Mandatory)
$VMNames = "<my vm name>"

# Name of vCenter or standalone host VMs to backup reside on (Mandatory)
$HostName = "<my hostname>"

# Directory that VM backups should go to (Mandatory; for instance, C:\Backup)
$Directory = "\\1.2.3.4\backup"

# Desired compression level (Optional; Possible values: 0 - None, 4 - Dedupe-friendly, 5 - Optimal, 6 - High, 9 - Extreme) 
$CompressionLevel = "5"

# Quiesce VM when taking snapshot (Optional; VMware Tools are required; Possible values: $True/$False)
$EnableQuiescence = $False

# Protect resulting backup with encryption key (Optional; $True/$False)
$EnableEncryption = $False

# Encryption Key (Optional; path to a secure string)
$EncryptionKey = ""

# Retention settings (Optional; By default, VeeamZIP files are not removed and kept in the specified location for an indefinite period of time. 
# Possible values: Never , Tonight, TomorrowNight, In3days, In1Week, In2Weeks, In1Month)
$Retention = "Never"

##################################################################
#                   Notification Settings
##################################################################

# Enable notification (Optional)
$EnableNotification = $False

# Email SMTP server
$SMTPServer = ""

# Email FROM
$EmailFrom = "" 

# Email TO
$EmailTo = ""

# Email subject
$EmailSubject = ""

##################################################################
#                   Email formatting 
##################################################################

$style = "<style>BODY{font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt;}"
$style = $style + "TABLE{border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;}"
$style = $style + "TH{border: 1px solid black; background: #dddddd; padding: 5px; }"
$style = $style + "TD{border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px; }"
$style = $style + "</style>"

##################################################################
#                   End User Defined Variables
##################################################################

#################### DO NOT MODIFY PAST THIS LINE ################
Asnp VeeamPSSnapin

$Server = Get-VBRServer -name $HostName
$MesssagyBody = @()

foreach ($VMName in $VMNames)
{
  $VM = Find-VBRViEntity -Name $VMName -Server $Server

  If ($EnableEncryption)
  {
    $EncryptionKey = Add-VBREncryptionKey -Password (cat $EncryptionKey | ConvertTo-SecureString)
    $ZIPSession = Start-VBRZip -Entity $VM -Folder $Directory -Compression $CompressionLevel -DisableQuiesce:(!$EnableQuiescence) -AutoDelete $Retention -EncryptionKey $EncryptionKey
  }

  Else 
  {
    $ZIPSession = Start-VBRZip -Entity $VM -Folder $Directory -Compression $CompressionLevel -DisableQuiesce:(!$EnableQuiescence) -AutoDelete $Retention
  }

  If ($EnableNotification) 
  {
    $TaskSessions = $ZIPSession.GetTaskSessions().logger.getlog().updatedrecords
    $FailedSessions =  $TaskSessions | where {$_.status -eq "EWarning" -or $_.Status -eq "EFailed"}

  if ($FailedSessions -ne $Null)
  {
    $MesssagyBody = $MesssagyBody + ($ZIPSession | Select-Object @{n="Name";e={($_.name).Substring(0, $_.name.LastIndexOf("("))}} ,@{n="Start Time";e={$_.CreationTime}},@{n="End Time";e={$_.EndTime}},Result,@{n="Details";e={$FailedSessions.Title}})
  }

  Else
  {
    $MesssagyBody = $MesssagyBody + ($ZIPSession | Select-Object @{n="Name";e={($_.name).Substring(0, $_.name.LastIndexOf("("))}} ,@{n="Start Time";e={$_.CreationTime}},@{n="End Time";e={$_.EndTime}},Result,@{n="Details";e={($TaskSessions | sort creationtime -Descending | select -first 1).Title}})
  }

  }   
}
If ($EnableNotification)
{
$Message = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage $EmailFrom, $EmailTo
$Message.Subject = $EmailSubject
$Message.IsBodyHTML = $True
$message.Body = $MesssagyBody | ConvertTo-Html -head $style | Out-String
$SMTP = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SMTPServer)
$SMTP.Send($Message)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When running jobs in the console, this is not an issue as the job will use the credentials specified – this is only an issue when creating jobs from command line. The fix for this is to set the "Veeam Data Mover" service to run as an account that does have permissions to write to the target.